# Testing React component that fetches data asynchronously

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm fairly new to `testing-library`, and trying to figure out how to write some tests for a component that fetches data asynchronously.

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-wozniak-ol69c).

I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to do it with `testing-library`. Especially since it involves fetching data asynchronously and there is debounce.

The assertion I'm trying to make is fairly simple(you can see it in the test file) and it'll be great if someone could help me figure this out.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you want to fetch the data asynchronously in your unit tests? I would recommend mocking your API calls and return fixtures which makes the expectations also a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this post](https://www.polvara.me/posts/how-to-test-asynchronous-methods/) I explain how to deal with API calls in RTL.

As for the `debounce` I suggest you just mock it out so that it doesn't run in your tests:

```js
jest.mock('lodash/debounce', () => fn => fn)
```

Or if you want something a bit more complete:

```js
jest.mock('lodash/debounce', () => fn => {
  const debounced = function(...args) {
    const context = this
    return fn.apply(context, args)
   }
   debounced.cancel = () => {}
   return debounced
})
```

Comment: Great answer, and the your post was really helpful. Had to do a little more to get my actual tests(not the simplified stuff in the example) to work but definitely built on top of your ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you found it useful!